# Can't get correct XSLT output

Tags: xslt

I have a XML like this:

```
<Section>
    <Chapter>
        <Head>Heading</Head>
        <nametable>
            <nametitle>MyTitle</nametitle>
            <namedomain>MyDomain</namedomain>
            <namevalue>value1</namevalue>
        </nametable>
        <nametable>
            <nametitle>MyTitle2</nametitle>
            <namedomain>MyDomain2</namedomain>
            <namevalue>value2</namevalue>
        </nametable>
    </Chapter>
</Section>
```

I'd like to get this output:

```
MyTitle2
MyDomain2
value2
```

I've used `text()` function to check the text content but it doesn't print anything.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="//Chapter">
    <xsl:comment>Ignore Head tag</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Head)]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nametable">
     <xsl:for-each select="nametitle">
        <xsl:if test="text()='MyTitle2'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="nametitle" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nametitle">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What did I do wrong ?.

Thanks!.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is here**:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="nametitle">
    <xsl:if test="text()='MyTitle2'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="nametitle" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If the test is successful, then templates will be applied to the `nametitle` child of the current node.

**However, the current node is `nametitle` and it has no `nametitle` children** -- so no nodes are selected and no templates applied.

**Solution**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="nametable[nametitle = 'MyTitle2']/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Section>
    <Chapter>
        <Head>Heading</Head>
        <nametable>
            <nametitle>MyTitle</nametitle>
            <namedomain>MyDomain</namedomain>
            <namevalue>value1</namevalue>
        </nametable>
        <nametable>
            <nametitle>MyTitle2</nametitle>
            <namedomain>MyDomain2</namedomain>
            <namevalue>value2</namevalue>
        </nametable>
    </Chapter>
</Section>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
        MyTitle2
        MyDomain2
        value2
```

Comment: @JohnX: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Please, consider accepting this answer (hint: by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer).

Comment: I have one question, if I replace the '<xsl:value-of select="."/>' with '<xsl:apply-templates />' and provide a template match for nametitle (that contains <xsl:value-of select="." />) your solution would print MyTitle instead of MyTitle2. I'm wondering why is that because the check is MyTitle2.

Comment: @JohnX: The comment format isn't good for writing code -- I cannot understand what is the complete modified code you are talking about. May I recommend that you ask a new question for this new problem?

Comment: OK, I've posted a new question. Thanks!.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425190/cant-get-correct-xslt-output

Comment: Dimitre, I've posted a new question. Thanks!. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714365/cant-get-xslt-node-copy-to-work-when-dealing-with-two-xml-files

Comment: @JohnX: I will have to look at this not earlier than after 12 hours. BTW, Michael Kay has given you the correct solution -- I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two alternatives that produce the same result:

```
<xsl:template match="nametitle[text()='MyTitle2']">
 <xsl:value-of select="parent::node()"/>
 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="*[nametitle[text()='MyTitle2']]">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```