# Can't get correct XSLT output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Section>
    <Chapter>
        <nametable>
            <namerow>
                <namecell stuff="1">
                    <entity>A</entity>
                </namecell>
                <namecell stuff="2">
                    <entity>B</entity>
                </namecell>
            </namerow>
        </nametable>
    </Chapter>
</Section>
```

My XSLT is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Chapter//nametable"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nametable">
        <xsl:for-each select="./namerow">
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/@stuff"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Odd is I'm getting an output in this order 1 2 A B, I thought I'm going to get 1 A 2 B.

Not sure why is that ?.

TIA,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your problem is here**:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="./namerow">
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/@stuff"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell" />
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Unlike in XSLT 1.0 in XSLT 2.0 the `xsl:value-of` instruction outputs *all* items of the sequence specified in its `select` attribute.

This means that

```
<xsl:value-of select="./namecell/@stuff"/>
```

outputs all `stuff` attributes (1 and 2)

then the next instruction:

```
           <xsl:value-of select="./namecell" />
```

outputs the string value of the two `namecell` children -- respectively `"A"` and `"B"`.

**Solution**:

**Replace**:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="./namerow">
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/@stuff"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell" />
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**with**:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="./namerow">
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/(@stuff|entity)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**The complete code with this modification is**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Chapter//nametable"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="nametable">
            <xsl:for-each select="./namerow">
                <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/(@stuff|entity)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Section>
    <Chapter>
        <nametable>
            <namerow>
                <namecell stuff="1">
                    <entity>A</entity>
                </namecell>
                <namecell stuff="2">
                    <entity>B</entity>
                </namecell>
            </namerow>
        </nametable>
    </Chapter>
</Section>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
1 A 2 B
```

**Second solution** (probably what you intended to do in the first place):

**Replace**:

```
    <xsl:template match="nametable">
        <xsl:for-each select="./namerow">
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/@stuff"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="./namecell" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

**with**:

```
    <xsl:template match="nametable">
        <xsl:for-each select="namerow/namecell">
            <xsl:value-of select="@stuff"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="entity"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Now you again get the wanted result**:

```
1A2B
```

Comment: Dimitri: What does this  <xsl:value-of select="./namecell/(@stuff|entity)"/> really do ?.

Comment: @JohnX: `<xsl:value-of select="./namecell/(@stuff|entity)"/>` outputs as text nodes the string values of each `stuff` attribute and `entity` child of every `namecell` child of the current node. Here I use the Xpath *union* operator `|`. Such union in a location step is possible only in XPath 2.0 -- syntactically illegal in XPath 1.0.

Comment: Dimitre: some more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448446/output-values-in-a-certain-way-using-xslt-xpath-2-0. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

I am using msxml, am getting `1 A` as op :|

Well here is a solution for you it works like gem :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Section/Chapter/nametable/namerow/namecell">
    <xsl:value-of select="@stuff"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><!--inserting a space-->
    <xsl:value-of select="entity"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><!--inserting a space-->
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's what I did to get the correct answer, I'm using Saxon EE but I don't understand why my original post doesn't work as it supposed to ?.

Comment: That might be because you are using `/namecell/@stuff` instead of `/@stuff` .. I am not really focused to xslt 2.0 so not sure ..

Comment: msxml doesn't allow :/ N my tool background coding is based upon .net :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the behavior you see is that you iterate over namerow. You will get 1A2B if you will instead iterate over namecell as: `<xsl:for-each select="namerow/namecell"><xsl:value-of select="@stuff"/><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:for-each>`. You'll want to remember that each XPath such as `@stuff` gives you not necessarily one value (a node), but rather a set of values (a nodeset). That set will commonly happen to contain only one value, but don't be fooled.

Another syntax for the same thing: `<xsl:for-each select="namerow"><xsl:for-each select="namecell"><xsl:value-of select="@stuff"/><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:for-each></xsl:for-each>`

P.S. Just as in a filesystem path, you don't have to write "./" before an XPath.