# Can't get XSLT node copy to work when dealing with two XML files

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have two XML files:

```
data1.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tables>
    <table>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>Sedan</carType>
                <gasType>Gasoline</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colnane="4">B</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A1</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>Truck</carType>
                <gasType>Diesel</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B1</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C1</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
 </tables>

data2.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tables>
    <table>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>SedanXYZ</carType>
                <gasType>GasolineXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A2</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>Motorcycle</carType>
                <gasType>Gasoline</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">U</cell>
            <cell colname="5">Z</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A1</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>TruckXYZ</carType>
                <gasType>DieselXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B1</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C1</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
 </tables>
```

Basically I want to copy whatever contained in colname="2" from data2.xml to data1.xml and keep the rest of the data in data1.xml the same. The keys to find the equality are colname="4" and colname="5". My XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">   

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc2"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:message>Starting off</xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cell[@colname='2']">
        <xsl:variable name="key-value">
            <xsl:call-template name="key-value"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="document($doc2)//row">
           <xsl:if test="key('keyx', $key-value)">   
               <xsl:copy-of select="cell[@colname='2']"/>
           </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Just copy any other elements, attributes, etc. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:key name="keyx" match="row" 
    use="concat(cell[@colname='4'], cell[@colname='5'])"/>

    <!-- This template retrives the key value for an element -->
    <xsl:template name="key-value">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(../cell[@colname='4'],../cell[@colname='5'])"/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result I'm expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<tables>
   <table>
       <row>
            <cell colname="1">A</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>SedanXYZ</carType>
                <gasType>GasolineXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C</cell>
       </row>
       <row>
            <cell colname="1">A1</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>TruckXYZ</carType>
                <gasType>DieselXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B1</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C1</cell>
       </row>
   </table>
</tables>

BUT I'm getting incorrect output like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<tables>
    <table>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>SedanXYZ</carType>
                <gasType>GasolineXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="2">
                <carType>Motorcycle</carType>
                <gasType>Gasoline</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="2">
               <carType>TruckXYZ</carType>
               <gasType>DieselXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell colname="1">A1</cell>
            <cell colname="2">
               <carType>SedanXYZ</carType>
               <gasType>GasolineXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="2">
               <carType>Motorcycle</carType>
               <gasType>Gasoline</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="2">
               <carType>TruckXYZ</carType>
               <gasType>DieselXYZ</gasType>
            </cell>
            <cell colname="4">B1</cell>
            <cell colname="5">C1</cell>
       </row>
    </table>
</tables>
```

So several questions:

1. What's wrong with my XSLT ?
2. What's the technique to debug the key calls ?.

   Thanks you!.

   John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use the key function here, because you need to create a key set on $doc2 and XML Spy does not allow me to do so. And the key on the source XML will not suffice.
So I wrote another solution for you, not using key at all:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">   

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc2"><xsl:copy-of select="document('C:\test\data2.xml')"/></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cell[@colname='2']">
        <xsl:variable name="keyValue" select="concat(../cell[@colname='4'], ../cell[@colname='5'])"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$doc2/tables/table/row[concat(cell[@colname='4'], cell[@colname='5']) = $keyValue]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="cell[@colname='2']"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Just copy any other elements, attributes, etc. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Oh, and by the way, you have a couple of `colnane` typo's in the source files.

**EDIT** forgot about the third argument in the key function :-(. So adding

```
<xsl:key name="keyx" match="row" use="concat(cell[@colname='4'], cell[@colname='5'])"/>
```

and changing the for-each to

```
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyx', $keyValue, $doc2)">
        <xsl:copy-of select="cell[@colname='2']"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

will achieve your objectives.

**EDIT 2**

OK the above replaces colname="2" cells, but does not leave data1 ones when no data2 matches are found.

Use the following instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0">   

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="doc2"/> <!-- supplied in parameter list in specific tool -->
    <xsl:key name="keyx" match="row" use="concat(cell[@colname='4'], cell[@colname='5'])"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cell[@colname='2']">
        <xsl:variable name="keyValue" select="concat(../cell[@colname='4'], ../cell[@colname='5'])"/>
        <xsl:variable name="doc2Matches" select="key('keyx', $keyValue, document($doc2))"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$doc2Matches">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$doc2Matches[1]/cell[@colname='2']"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Just copy any other elements, attributes, etc. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Don't use Windows filenames as an argument to doc(). Some processors will accept them, but it's wrong: the argument is supposed to be a URI, not a platform-dependent filename.

Comment: @MichaelKay good point - but I only used it for quick testing purposes. What do you suggest to use as uri for a local filesystem file like mine?

Comment: Hi Maestro, looks like it can't run, it complains about "Required item type of third argument of key() is node(); supplied value has item type xs:untypedAtomic".

Comment: @JohnX typical - it runs OK in the XML Spy version I am using - what XSL parser are you using? Or maybe this is because of MK's remark on uri's? If you use the same $doc2 parameter as before, you will have to supply document($doc2) as third argument, I guess.

Comment: Hi Maestro, yeah using document($doc2) runs the code, but there are no colname='2', it's empty, doesn't get copied ?.

Comment: @JohnX did you correct the **colnane** typo's and remove the ../ from the key definition?

Comment: Hi Maestro, the colnane has been fixed, I use your version, including the for-each modification.

Comment: @JohnX meet me in the chatroom called XSLT chat (specific issue), then we can determine what's wrong while chatting.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your code: you're using key() without the third argument. The third argument tells the system which document you want to search. If you omit it, it searches the document containing the context node, whereas you want to search the "other" document. With this kind of task it's best to have two global variables containing the two document nodes, so you can switch readily between them.

Personally I tackle this kind of merging task using xsl:for-each-group. In the select attribute of for-each-group, select all the relevant elements from both documents. In the body of for-each-group, if current-group() contains a single element, output that one, otherwise decide which one to output based on a test such as `root(.) is $doc-two`.

Comment: Good point - I keep forgetting about the third argument of the key function :-)